# Limit Cycles of a Simple Pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

In [this pdf file](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/%7Emcc/Chaos_Course/Lesson2/Pendulum.pdf) the dynamical behavior of a simple pendulum is discussed. The equation of motion for a pendulum with no dissipation is:

$$\dot{\theta}=\omega, \qquad \dot{\omega}=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$$

The phase portrait is given in the figure below.

[image]

The limit cycle is defined as an **isolated closed trajectory** in phase space. This means that there exists a neighborhood around the limit cycle, in which no other closed trajectories exist. Based on this definition the harmonic oscillator does not have a limit cycle, because the closed orbits are concentric ellipses and are arbitrarily close to each other. In other words, no neighborhood exists around a closed cycle which doesn't contain another closed cycle.

Based on this definition isn't this also the case for a simple pendulum for energies below the critical energy? It seems to me that for any neighborhood of a closed cycle, by changing the energy we can find another closed cycle in that neighborhood for the pendulum. Am I wrong? Can these closed orbits be characterized as limit cycles?

Comment: There are many sources explaining the concept of the limit cycle. You can check this link if you want: https://youtu.be/EocHy9kufpA

Comment: The phase portrait is given in the image for a pendulum with no dissipation. Yet, the trajectories are called limit cycles in the portrait. So they received the name and it doesn't have dissipation
 My question is why and how.

Comment: It's not just the plot. Here is a part of the text: "The remaining orbits are periodic in time, and are called “limit cycles”. For
small energies, near(0, 0)the limit cycles are the familiar simple harmonic motion,
represented by circles or ellipses (stretched circles) in the phase space."

Comment: Ali, I turned my comments into an answer and deleted them, you might want to delete yours too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's a mistake on the part of the author, who is using "limit cycle" meaning simply "cycle".

A [limit cycle](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Limit_cycles_of_planar_polynomial_vector_fields) is a periodic orbit ("cycle") that is the accumulation point (for $t \to \infty$ or $t \to -\infty$) for all points in a given neighborhood — a condition which can't be satisfied by a Hamiltonian system (where phase space volume is preserved).

Even when talking about the invariant tori of the standard map, in his [chapter](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/%7Emcc/Chaos_Course/Lesson27/Hamiltonian.pdf) on Hamiltonian systems, Michael Cross call them "limit cycles":

[image]

while conservative systems clearly can't have attracting sets.